# Does Atomic variable flush cache only on cache line where it is at?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

I try to use atomic variable as possible as instead of mutex.
Because Atomic variable works on user mode but mutex works on kernel mode, So atomic is much faster than mutex.

But i have question about atomic variable.
Does Atomic variable do acquire, release only cache line where it is at.
If it is right, To Release All cache lines, Should I use mutex???

Comment: `std::atomic` only makes the single variable Atomic.  If you need transactional type behaviour where multiple variables have to be updated and all the updates made visible (to other threads) at the same point then you need an `std::mutex`.

Comment: If you need memory barrier, use memoriy barrier. atomic are just afford to be in the same order with respect to other atomis, nothing to do with cache. BTW there are quite a lots of caches thus you need to be careful with any of them.

Comment: @OznOg it is not a true. Most of the strongest atomics ordering like `seq_cst` or `acr_rel` also impacts memory ordering for non-atomic variables. The difference between `release` and `consume` is all about that non-atomic variables visibility on different threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All operations on the atomic object itself are atomic: there is a single ordering for all modifications across all threads (for that specific atomic object). The acquire/release stuff is therefore about the visibility of modifying *other* memory relative to some modification of an atomic variable (though `memory_order_relaxed` also affects how operations on that atomic object relate to other operations on that atomic object).

For example, if one thread sets some data to a value, and then sets an atomic variable to some agreed-upon value, if another thread sees the atomic variable with that value, proper use of the acquire/release flags on the atomic read/write allows the other thread to *also* safely access the other data set by the thread that set the atomic variable.

So those flags apply to potentially *all* memory operations in the process.

Also, you shouldn't really think of it in terms of "releasing cache lines" or whatever. The C++ memory model should be read in terms of itself: what data is visible and accessible to which threads due to what sequence of operations. Let the implementations work out the details.